# Meteor.js - how to rerender a template on login

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, meteor, leaflet

I have an app with a leaflet map on every page in a template named "map".
In that map I'm adding a contextmenu in the "Template.map.rendered" function.

Where it get tricky, is that I want to add a disconnect link and a profile link in that contextmenu when the user is logged in, but not when the user is not.
The map is there even if you are not connected.

my problem right now is that my map is not rerendered when I login or logout of the app.
I tryed a couple of solution that I found on google, but nothing seem to work and i'm a bit lost here.

It's my first meteor app.

code:

```
Template.map.rendered = function(){
    L.Icon.Default.imagePath = 'packages/leaflet/images';

    var map = L.map('map', {
        doubleClickZoom: false,
        contextmenu: true,
        contextmenuWidth: 160,
        contextmenuItems: [{
            text: 'Show coordinates',
            callback: function(event){
                console.log(event);
            },
            icon: 'images/icons/mini-map-pin.png'
        }]
    }).setView([Session.get('mapLatitude'), Session.get('mapLongitude')], Session.get('mapZoom'));

    map.on('dragend zoomend', function(event){
        //map position and zoom are saved in session on every action so they
        //stay the same when the template is rerendered
        Session.set("mapLatitude", map.getCenter().lat);
        Session.set("mapLongitude", map.getCenter().lng);
        Session.set("mapZoom", map.getZoom());
    });

    if( Meteor.loggingIn() ){
        map.contextmenu.addItem('-');
        map.contextmenu.addItem({
            text: 'My profile',
            callback: function(event){
                console.log(event);
            },
            icon: 'images/icons/profile.png'
        });
        map.contextmenu.addItem({
            text: 'Disconnect',
            callback: function(event){
                console.log(event);
            },
            icon: 'images/icons/logout.png'
        });
    }

    L.tileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap.BlackAndWhite').addTo(map);
}
```

the map template is simply this

```
template(name="map")
    div#map
```

and the login is the standard "account-base" with "accounts-ui-bootstrap-3"

edit: ah and i'm using Jade instead of Blaze if that change something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your code has a race condition because `Meteor.loggingIn()` will only be true for a short time, and the template would have to be rendered only in that window in order for the menu items to appear. Furthermore, as you discovered, it won't run again with the user logs out.

I don't know what your map plugin is capable of, but assuming it has add/remove functionality, you could try using an [autorun](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun) inside of your rendered function instead of the `if( Meteor.loggingIn() )` code above. Give something like this a try:

```
Template.map.rendered = function() {
  // create the map for all users
  var map = ...;

  // replace the if( Meteor.loggingIn() ) section with this code
  this.autorun(function() {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
      // add code here to add menu items
      map.contextmenu.addItem(...);
    } else {
      // add code here to remove menu items
      map.contextmenu.removeItem(...);
    }
  });
};
```

The idea is that it will create a reactive computation which will run whenever the user logs in or out. In each case you can update your map's menu as appropriate.

Comment: Well thanks for that answer, if it's not the solution, at the very least it answer many question I had, like where to use autorun. Leaflet contextmenu plugin does have a add and remove item functions so I'll do it that way. I wanted to do it like that at first, but could not figure out how to do it in meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Set a session variable called "logged" which will be false by default and set it to true when logged in. then add "Session.get("logged") in any template you want rerendered when this session changes,
Whenever you use "Session.get" inside a template Meteor creates a dependency and rerenders the template when it detects that a dependent has changed.

if you dont want to use session variables for this you can read in the Meteor docs on "Deps" which is used for creating dependencies.